# Photoshop font size smaller than it should be

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

I have a PSD at 72 dpi, for a web interface. The developers implemented everything based on the PSD, including font sizes, but font sizes were an issue.

I'm having a hard time coming up with an explanation for this. I have a Retina 5k iMac, with a screen resolution of 5120x2880.

On the left below is Photoshop text at size 26px at 100% magnification, and on the left is just a TextEdit document with size 26 text:

[image]

You can see that the discrepancy is not subtle. The right is almost 2x as large. The result of this is that any implementation of PSD -> HTML/CSS results in all the text looking too big, since I have to use large font sizes in Photoshop to get it to the size it would normally be in other mediums.

Can anyone offer any solutions or explanations for this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the problem was. Since I'm designing on a Retina display, I needed to set the Image -> Image Size resolution to double the standard resolution, 72 -> 144.

Then when I send it to the developer, he should set it to whatever his display's resolution is, in this case 72. This way we get consistent results.

These links helped me out:

http://louis-andre.net/retina-photoshop/

[How does font size translate on a Retina Display in Photoshop?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/63107/how-does-font-size-translate-on-a-retina-display-in-photoshop)